# Rxjs error with pipe of operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an error in switchMap operator:

```
@Injectable()
export class AvailableStoreTypesLoadedEffect {
constructor(private actions$: Actions,
          private service: AvailableService) {

}

 @Effect()
 AvailableStoreTypesLoadedEffect$ = this.actions$
 .ofType(FETCH_AVAILABLE_STORE_TYPES)
 .pipe(
   switchMap(action => this.service.fetchAvailableStoreTypes()),//Error:(22, 9) TS2684:The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.
   map(res => new AvailableStoreTypesLoaded(res))
  );
}
```

I tried with:

```
Observable.of({})
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => Observable.of({}))//Error:(22, 9) TS2684:The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.
  );
```

but I get the same error.

My environment is:

- angular 5.0.3
- typescript 2.4.2
- rxjs 5.5.2

Comment: Is your `this.service.fetchAvailableStoreTypes()` returning an observable?

Comment: Yes, I return `return Observable.of({});`

Comment: I tried with: `Observable.of({})
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => Observable.of({}))
      );` and I get the same error

Comment: If you could post a little bit more code than this, I think it would be really helpful to undestand your problem. It would be escpecially helpful to see what the `pipe` is called on, how `fetchAvailableStoryTypes` looks like and how `AvailableStoryStypesLoaded` looks like.

Comment: I edited the post with more data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I imported the library from `import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';` but it must be imported from `import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`